# Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default

Tags: python, ubuntu, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

I am writing a telegram bot on the aiogram framework. Everything was good when I run it, but today I am getting error,`Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default` I do not know what's problem.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
**Here is the full error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mirodil/.local/share/virtualenvs/allinone-kbyzCwMv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1154, in _create_direct_connection
    hosts = await asyncio.shield(host_resolved)
  File "/home/mirodil/.local/share/virtualenvs/allinone-kbyzCwMv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 880, in _resolve_host
    addrs = await self._resolver.resolve(host, port, family=self._family)
  File "/home/mirodil/.local/share/virtualenvs/allinone-kbyzCwMv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/resolver.py", line 33, in resolve
    infos = await self._loop.getaddrinfo(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 825, in getaddrinfo
    return await self.run_in_executor(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mirodil/.local/share/virtualenvs/allinone-kbyzCwMv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 139, in make_request
    async with session.post(url, data=req, **kwargs) as response:
  File "/home/mirodil/.local/share/virtualenvs/allinone-kbyzCwMv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1138, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/mirodil/.local/share/virtualenvs/allinone-kbyzCwMv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 535, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/home/mirodil/.local/share/virtualenvs/allinone-kbyzCwMv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 542, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/mirodil/.local/share/virtualenvs/allinone-kbyzCwMv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 907, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/mirodil/.local/share/virtualenvs/allinone-kbyzCwMv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1166, in _create_direct_connection
    raise ClientConnectorError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Temporary failure in name resolution]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 18, in <module>
    executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=on_startup)
  File "/home/mirodil/.local/share/virtualenvs/allinone-kbyzCwMv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 45, in start_polling
    executor.start_polling(
  File "/home/mirodil/.local/share/virtualenvs/allinone-kbyzCwMv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 320, in start_polling
    loop.run_until_complete(self._startup_polling())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/mirodil/.local/share/virtualenvs/allinone-kbyzCwMv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 372, in _startup_polling
    await self._welcome()
  File "/home/mirodil/.local/share/virtualenvs/allinone-kbyzCwMv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 361, in _welcome
    user = await self.dispatcher.bot.me
  File "/home/mirodil/.local/share/virtualenvs/allinone-kbyzCwMv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py", line 30, in me
    setattr(self, '_me', await self.get_me())
  File "/home/mirodil/.local/share/virtualenvs/allinone-kbyzCwMv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py", line 228, in get_me
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_ME, payload)
  File "/home/mirodil/.local/share/virtualenvs/allinone-kbyzCwMv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/base.py", line 231, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "/home/mirodil/.local/share/virtualenvs/allinone-kbyzCwMv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 142, in make_request
    raise exceptions.NetworkError(f"aiohttp client throws an error: {e.__class__.__name__}: {e}")
aiogram.utils.exceptions.NetworkError: Aiohttp client throws an error: ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Temporary failure in name resolution]
```

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are running your Python telegram bot script on PythonAnywhere. If this is true, ensure you have the proxy setup integrated in the bot instance:

```
bot = Bot(token='YOUR API TOKEN GOES HERE', proxy='http://proxy.server:3128')
```

If that has been setup and you still get the TLS-in-TLS-related error from PythonAnywhere:

1. Tap consoles on the Menu option.
2. Close the console in which your script is running.
3. Run the script again.

Answer (score 1):

Your base url should be `https://api.telegram.org/`, with that being said it is common to see `ConnectionError` and `ReadTimeout` during polling.

But, looking at the error `socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution` there is an issue in getting the address info for the host. I'd start with ruling out any connection issues and then check your `/etc/hosts` file to see if there are any misconfigurations.

If neither works, try polling the API directly to see if the problem still exists.

In general, setting up webhooks are much better than long polling.
It takes a bit of a setup, requires an API and a reverse proxy like ngrok, but once it is up and running, it is a very hassle free and elegant solution compared to long polling. I created a POC for telegram webhooks, which might be of help if you're looking to switch from long polling to webhooks.

**Proof of concept**

**Python**: https://github.com/thevickypedia/telegram-webhook

**Java**: https://github.com/thevickypedia/telegram-webhook-spring